# SQLite help for joining and count

Tags: sqlite, join, count

I have 2 tables:

**tblTransactions**:

```
transID | type | userID
```

**tblusers**:

```
userID | name ;
```

Now I want my results to be like:

```
name |count( transactionType1(where type=1)) | transactionType1(where type=2)

mr.1 |  2                                    | 4
mr.2 |  3                                    | 5
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Show us **your efforts** and explain where you're stuck. We'll be glad to help - but we don't just write code for you

Answer (score 0):

Group by the user and then you can use aggregate functions like `sum` to count the type (with a condition)

```
select u.name, 
       sum(type = 1) as type1_count,
       sum(type = 2) as type2_count
from tblusers u 
left join tblTransactions t on u.userid = t.userid
group by u.name
```